# How to remove "extra" blank rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

Table with five relevant fields;

```
ID (Autoincrement,unique, etc)
ID_customer - ties in each row to another table with customers, not unique, not NULL
value1 - can be 0 and NULL (NULL is not 0)
value2 - can be 0 and NULL (NULL is not 0)
type - can be 1 or 0
```

I want to go through the table and find each case where a customer has more than one row and if there are multiple rows with the same value on type, remove any such rows that have only 0s in their value columns. For example;

```
 1 1 40 8 1
 2 1  0 0 1  <--
 3 1 30 5 0
 4 1 45 8 0
```

In this case the command would need to remove the indicated row, but leave the others intact. Not too difficult. Something like this would probably work (repeat for type = 0):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE value1 = 0 AND value2 = 0 AND type = 1
   AND ID_customer IN
       (SELECT ID_customer
        FROM table
        WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY ID_customer HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

The problem is cases like these could exist:

```
 5 2 0 0 1
 6 2 0 0 1 <--
 7 2 0 0 0
 8 2 0 0 0 <--
```

In which case I would want to remove two of the rows, but not all rows. Is there some way for me to remove duplicates rows, but only if the value columns are 0s? Would this work (again, repeated for type = 0), or am I missing something?

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE
WHERE value1 = 0 AND value2 = 0 AND TYPE = 1
  AND ID NOT IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE value1 = 0 AND value2 = 0 AND TYPE = 1
     GROUP BY ID_customer)
```

edit: I've looked into other duplicate removal questions, but I can't find one which defines a subquery in the manner my table requires (in where I want to keep SOME of the duplicates).

Comment: Can there be more than one duplicate per user and type?

Comment: Yes, as long as the value columns are non-zero.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Again, the topic you marked as duplicate answers the 2nd part only, not the 1st part. The delete query in the question would give a syntax error (cannot select from the same table that is being modified)

Comment: Why does the 7 2 0 0 0 row not meet the criteria for deletion?

Comment: @shadow indeed. I wasn't aware of this. I apologize.

Comment: @John Cannot delete both 7 2 0 0 0 and 8 2 0 0 0 as I need to keep one line for customer ID 2 with type 0 that has 0 values. I want to remove extras, but not all inputs (that would mean customer ID 2 would get NULL instead of 0s, which are differently valued).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the first problem:

Your query for the first problem causes an error (`You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

However if you use a derived table (nesting the subquery) it works just fine:

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE value1 = 0
    AND value2 = 0
    AND TYPE = 1
    AND ID_customer IN
        (SELECT ID_customer
         FROM
             (SELECT ID_customer
              FROM table1
              WHERE TYPE = 1
              GROUP BY ID_customer
              HAVING count(*) > 0) AS derived)
```

For the second problem the approach is quite similar but also using the ID field:

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE ID IN
        (SELECT dups.ID
         FROM
             (SELECT t1.ID
              FROM table1 t1
              JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.ID_Customer = t2.ID_Customer
              AND t1.value1 = t2.value1
              AND t1.value2 = t2.value2
              AND t1.type = t2.type
              AND t1.ID > t2.ID
              WHERE t1.value1 = 0
                  AND t2.value2 =0 ) AS dups);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing that entire double table hoop, other than to guarantee that you pick the "first" row? Wouldn't a similar solution as you provided to the first problem work equally well to workaround the problem that you can't delete from the same table you're referencing?

Comment: With `entire double table hoop` I guess you mean the `self-JOIN`. It's actually an alternative way of finding duplicates, you can probably do the same by using `group by`. It just felt comfortable to me doing it this way.

Comment: It would be nice if you could  accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I would add that a unique index on appropriate fields would indeed prevent the 2nd case :) A nice solution, though.